# Is there a site that emails out daily C# tips and tricks?

Tags: c#, newsletter

I subscribe to a newsletter from www.sqlservercentral.com that I like because each day I get an email digest with some interesting headlines & summaries of SQL Server articles that are already out there on the web.  It's a great way to learn something new a bit at a time.

Is there something like this for C#?

(If your favorite one is already listed, can you vote for it so I can see what's most popular?  Thanks!)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In addition to [codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/), I believe there are other sites like [C# Corner](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/), [C# help](http://www.csharphelp.com/) which does the same..

Couple more I found useful (Not specific to C#):

[visualstudiomagazine](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/)

[Dr. Dobb's](http://www.ddj.com/newsletters/)

Answer (score 5):

Have you ever considered subscribing to blogs? You can often get better content than the daily subscription emails and if you want can even become a part of the discussion through the comments. Two that are generally good for learning more about the trade and C# are [CodingBetter.com](http://codebetter.com/Default.aspx) and [Los Techies](http://www.lostechies.com/). If you are looking for something that is more of an aggregate of other sources [Scott Gu](http://weblogs.asp.net/Scottgu/) routinely puts out a list of links that can be very informative in addition to helpful walk through articles.

Good luck,

Answer (score 3):

check out [wwww.codeproject.com](http://wwww.codeproject.com) they have a lot of articles and various newsletters.

Answer (score 2):

You should try [dotnetkicks.com](http://www.dotnetkicks.com/) which delivers nice rss feed of the most relevant .net blogs (imho). If you want the RSS-Feed emailed to you try [feedblitz](http://www.feedblitz.com/) or [xfruits](http://xfruits.com/)